# BellY function call fails

Tags: evaluation, special-functions

I would very much appreciate to get an answer about the reason of the message I get calling the `BellY` function.

```
f1[nmax_, gcrel_, j_Integer] := Sum[
  BellY[j, K[1], Table[-(-gcrel)^K[2] gcrel, {K[2], 1, 1+j-K[1]}]]
    (Log^(K[1]))[-gcrel-E^(-gcrel nmax)/nmax], {K[1], 1, j}]

N[f1[1,0,1]]
```

I get this message.

> BellY::intnm: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position
> 1 in BellY[1.,1.,Table[0.^(1. +K[2.]),{K[2.],1.,1.}]].
>
> Out[1270]=-1. BellY[1.,1.,Table[0.^(1. +K[2.]),{K[2.],1.,1.}]]

It is my first time in this forum. Thank you for your help.

Comment: MMA version 12.1  If I try `f1[1,0,1]`I get a result of zero without any error messages. Have you tried a new kernel?

Comment: You have a syntax error. `Log[-gcrel - E^(-gcrel nmax)/nmax]^K[1]` is how you raise `Log` to a power.

Comment: Thank you Daniel and Bob very much!!. I changed the syntax as pointed out , however I still get the same message back. I’ll to use a new version of Mathematica like the 12.1. Thanks much again.